# Discrete Probability and counting

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

have a homework that I'm working on and my teacher said that I overcounted. Can you help me?

100 guests buy a drink/snack; 35 of them order wine, 25 order champagne, 20 order sweet snack, 15 order salty snack, 5 don't order anything. You talk to 5 people at random and find out what they bought. Find the probability that:

1. at least 3 of the guests bought a drink (of any kind)
2. you talk to 3 consecutive guests who bought sweet snack
3. of the last 2 guests you talked to, one bought a sweet snack and one bought a salty snack (order of the last 2 does not matter)

Comment: Share your work and we can point out what step you got wrong.  As it stands, this is a quintessential example of the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts. We can't tell where you went wrong if we can't see your work.